# Remote Desktop Connection Timeout

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

My Remote Desktop Connections are timing out after approximately 2 hours with this message:

> Your remote desktop services session ended because the remote computer
>   didn't receive any input from you.

I have these local group policies set to Never:

```
End a disconnected session,
Idle session limit,
Active session limit
```

Why is Remote Desktop still ending my sessions?

Comment: Are the policies set on the computer RDPing _into_?  Is the computer you're RDP'ing into on a domain?

Comment: The policies are set on the computer RDPed into.  The computer is on a domain.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. What did you end up doing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [RSOP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736424%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), [GPRESULT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733160.aspx) or the event viewer to verify your local policies are being applied successfully to the computer(s) that you are remoting in to with RDP.

Comment: The policies have been applied successfully.

Comment: Are you positive they are not being overridden by other group or domain policies? 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785665%28v=ws.10%29.aspx